# Limit reading children from a location through client side

Tags: firebase

```
var commentsRef = new Firebase('https://test.firebaseio.com/comments');
var last10Comments = commentsRef.limit(10);

//Rendering last 10 comments
last10Comments.on('child_added', function (snapshot) {

});
```

From the client side a **user can change the limit number** and can render all comments from comments reference.

Is there any way to **restrict reading limit** to some number at any point of time for a location?

Answer (score 1):

No, there isn't currently a way to put Firebase security rules around that type of limiting of data. Another approach that would work would be to have another section of the tree that contains a denormalized portion of the data that just contains the last 10 comments and nothing more.

Thanks for bringing this up. I've added this to our internal tracker to keep it in mind when we design V2 of our security API.